# Will a live Ubuntu Pen Drive slow down my Mac

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb, mac, macosx

I am planning on making a bootable live Ubuntu pen drive.Will this slow down my Mac in any way?Will any hardware problems arise?

Comment: Nothing bad should happen to your computer.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this on a Mac, once.  Running from a Live Media on a USB port will almost always be slower than running from an internal hard disk or SSD, but it will have no permanent effects unless you make changes to the system's hard disk.  In other words, when you reboot back to MacOS, with the Live Media unplugged, your system will be just as it was before trying Ubuntu.

Comment: Not exactly true, USB 3.0 now runs as fast as SATA. I think.

Comment: @MarkYisri Possibly true, IF and only if all components in the chain are 3.0 rated.  If you have a 2.0 compatible USB stick, or an internal cable to a front USB port that's only rated for USB 2.0, you'll only get the 2.0 speed.  And USB 3.0 pen drives cost several times what the ordinary 2.0 rated devices do, so if you have one lying around, it's probably the less expensive one (especially if you're on a budget, like most humans).

Comment: The flash memory hardware is often the bottleneck and limits the speed in USB pendrives. So if you want good performance, you should select a fast USB 3 pendrive. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed

Comment: @MarkYisri, most flash drives have flash memory in them that is not rated for anywhere near the full speed of USB 3.0. Not only that, but any USB 3.0 device is allowed to be incapable of full USB 3.0 speeds. The full speed is just a maximum limit.

Comment: @MarkYisri Although USB 3.0 spec itself is rated with speeds faster than SATA, the flash memory inside the usb stick must also be that fast, and I haven't seen any flash memory rated for speeds as high as an SSD.

Comment: I have usb type C... Won't that be technically faster than usb 3.0. And also a usb type C kindston pendrive which i am planning on using. And I have s WD external hard drive that i use with a usb c cable which is also pretty fast

Comment: @HELLDOZER That should do.

Answer (score 2):

Booting Linux live will give you an opportunity to test your hardware to see how the operating system runs on your computer without actually installing the OS.  It is recommended that you boot live to simply test the OS.  So, no nothing bad will happen.  It will give you a great opportunity to see how your mac will run with Ubuntu.